# Postfix sender_bcc_maps / ignore a specific user

Tags: postfix

I have sender_bcc_maps set up and working with postfix so that outgoing mail gets bcc'd to the sender's address. My configuration is more or less:

**main.cf**

```
sender_bcc_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp_sender_bcc
```

**regexp_sender_bcc**

```
/^([^@]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/ $1@example.com
```

This works great.  Now I have an email address `nobody@example.com` that I'd like to *exclude* from this configuration.

**Idea 1:** I first tried adding a row to route to a non-existent mailbox

```
/^nobody.*$/ nobody@example.com
```

Predictably, this results in an attempt to bcc that address and a bounceback since it doesn't exist.

**Idea 2:** Next I tried simply changing the target to an empty string:

```
/^nobody.*$/
```

This generates a warning and completely drops the outgoing mail as well:

```
warning: sender_bcc_maps lookup of nobody@example.com returns an empty string result
warning: sender_bcc_maps should return NO RESULT in case of NOT FOUND
warning: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
```

**Idea 3:** I then tried routing this mail to a local user:

```
/^nobody.*$/ nobody@localhost
```

This somewhat does the job but then all these messages are still delivered to the local mail system.

I'd like to do either one of these - preferring the former:

- configure sender_bcc_maps to *completely ignore* a specific sender's address
- configure postfix to *completely discard* mail to a specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configure sender_bcc_maps to completely ignore a specific sender's address:**

*(Credit to Viktor Dukhovni who answered this part of the question via **postfix-users**)*

The [Postfix regular expression table](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) is capable of conditional negated pattern matching by using `if !/pattern/flags ... endif`. In my case the following accomplishes what I am after:

```
if !/^nobody@/
/^([^@]+)@[a-z-]+\.[a-z]+/ $1@example.com
endif
```

There are also some small improvements to the domain matching part of the pattern since, as was pointed out, the regex is case insensitive by default.

**Configure postfix to completely discard mail to a specific user:**

The following worked for me to silently discard mail for the specified user. The server is running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS but this should work for nearly any Debian flavor:

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

In `/etc/postfix/transport`:

```
nobody@example.com discard:
```

Then in a shell run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
service postfix restart
```